# acccumulate using pyparsing

Tags: python, haskell, pyparsing, parsec

I have some data that can be parsed using the `OneorMore` function from pyparsing. Something like,

```
fun = OneorMore( foo.setResultsName("foo") +  bar.setResultsname("bar") )
```

where `bar` and `foo` are 2 parsers.

The problem with this function is that everytime that `OneorMore` match foo and bar parsers in the data stream, the corresponding values associated with the keys `"foo"` and `"bar"` are updated.But, 
how can I accumulate all the matched values of `foo` and `bar`?

I'm trying to implement something like the [many1](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.9/docs/Text-Parsec.html) monadic parser in Haskell, saving the result of parsing `foo` and `bar` in an Algebraic Data type, like

```
data FooBar a = FooBar a a

many1 :: ParsecT s u m a -> ParsecT s u m [a]

many1 parserFooBar :: ParsecT s u m [FooBar a]
```

How can I do this in python?

Comment: Would you be able to show "actual Python result" vs "desired Python result" for those not familiar with Haskell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, and am rusty with pyparsing, but I think [`Group`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.Group-class.html) will help you.

```
from pyparsing import *

text = 'abc123xyz456def789'
foo = Word(alphas)
bar = Word(nums)
fun = OneOrMore(Group(foo.setResultsName("foo") + bar.setResultsName("bar")))

results = fun.parseString(text)

#Print all foo
print [r.foo for r in results]
#Print all bar
print [r.bar for r in results]
```

Comment: This works very nicely - Groups will keep multiple results with the same name from clashing.